# Covariance of a Markov chain

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose I have a transition density (matrix) $K$, and I want to calculate the covariance between random variables at two different times.

\begin{align*}
Cov_{\mu_0}(X_n,X_{n+k})&=E_{\mu_0}(X_n-E_{\mu_n}X_n)(X_{n+k}-E_{\mu_{n+k}}X_{n+k})\\&=E_{\mu_n}(X_0-E_{\mu_0}X_0)(X_k-E_{\mu_k}X_k)\\&=\int\cdots\int(x_k-E_{\mu_k}X_k)(x_0-E_{\mu_0}X_0)K(x_{k-1},dx_k)K(x_{k-2},dx_{k-1})\cdots K(x_0,dx_1)\mu_n(dx_0)\\&=???
\end{align*}

How can I efficiently calculate this (both in theory and in computer simulation)? I know that

\begin{align*}
E_{\mu_0}f(X_k)&=\int\cdots\int f(x_k)K(x_{k-1},dx_k)\cdots K(x_0,dx_1)\mu_0(dx_0)\\&=???(\text{don't know the intermediate steps})\\&=\sum_i\mu^0_iK_{ij}^kf(x_i)\\&=\mu_0'K^{k}f
\end{align*}

Comment: Is $π$ the stable distribution? If so, then the second identity is incorrect except when $μ_0=π$.

Comment: Also, is the state space discrete or continuous? On the one hand the question says transition density, but on the other hand it says transition matrix, and both integration and summation are used.

Comment: I thought in measure theory integration and summation are the same

Comment: The first typo is edited

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use law of iterated expectation to simplify calculation